# How can I make a plot of the Higgs potential?

Tags: function-construction, physics

I was wondering, how would could I make a drawing of the Higgs potential aka "mexican hat potential". I am quite new to *Mathematica* and don't know where to look to learn how to implement such a complex function.

Comment: `Plot3D[#^2 - 1.5 # &@(x^2 + y^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is probably a common student misconception that it is "such a complex function". In actuality, it is quite simple. You should read: [A pedagogical example: the Mexican hat potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_potential#A_pedagogical_example:_the_Mexican_hat_potential). Very roughly you get the Mexican hat from interplay between two power functions: `a x^4` and `b x^2`. If parabola `b x^2` is inverted you get a bump in the center of your `a x^4` well. Let's see it on simplest algebraic example - define potential:

```
V[x_, T_] := x^4 + T x^2
```

Now rotate with `RevolutionPlot3D` to get a 3D shape out of 2D profile:

```
Manipulate[

 RevolutionPlot3D[V[x, T], {x, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 1.5 Pi}, 

  PlotPoints -> 30, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
  Mesh -> 20, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  SphericalRegion -> True, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5},
  ImageSize -> 400], 

{{T, -4, "Symmetry breaking parameter"}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

There is a nice [Demonstration "The Higgs Particle"](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheHiggsParticle/) by S. M. Blinder. You can often find  relevant things at the Demonstrations Project - code can be downloaded. A good start for your homework.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know the Mexican hat as the second derivative of the Gaussian function. See also the MexicanHatWavelet doc page.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries General shape has many common functional expressions. In physics of symmetry breaking what I mentioned is the simplest - see [A pedagogical example: the Mexican hat potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_potential#A_pedagogical_example:_the_Mexican_hat_potential)